# What are test artifacts needed for automated testing?

Tags: testing, automated-tests

i want to know the artifacts like test suites, test cases.
which ones are needed for Automated Testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can see about `Test suite` in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_suite), you can see about `Test cases` in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case).

And test suite and test cases are related. Both are need for automatic testing.
I hope when you are reading above two links you will be understand very well.